# string.join to append with some count and take rest to newline

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using string.join appending many data  which is separated by comma.If we have more than 50,only first 10 are visible and others are not visible.It will exit the screen size.I want to display the data with some count in string within screen.

```
_validatonDictionary.AddError(string.Empty, string.Join(",", findduplicate) + "-Settlement POD," + string.Join(",", finddupl) + "-Ded are duplicate PODS");
```

"findduplicate" and "finddupl"  is the list which consist of more than 100 item.I want to diplay maximum 10 one after other

Comment: Why you don't store the `string.Join` results in a local string variables with a meaningful names? That makes it easier for you to debug, to understand and to maintain your code. And it makes it easier for us to read your snippet. Single lines which force you to scroll horizontally should be avoided, not only in stackoverflow but also in visual studio.

Comment: Can you show the current output and the desired output

Comment: You can use `findduplicate.Take(10)` to get a maximum of 10 entries.

Comment: That's a job for the View, not the controller. Let the *view* format the lists of strings. There are a *lot* of ways you can display long lists with Javascript. As a list of values, some values with ellipsis, values+More button that shows the rest, values, More, *and* download. All of these work with a simple list of values. *None* of these is possible if you use one long string

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ceiling

```
//Calculating number of loops to run
int ceilingLimit = 10;
int iCount = finddupl.Count() / ceilingLimit + (finddupl.Count() % ceilingLimit != 0 ? 1 : 0);;
for (int iLoopCount = 0; iLoopCount < iCount; ++iLoopCount)
{
     int iRecordCount = finddupl.Count() >= ceilingLimit ? ceilingLimit : finddupl.Count();
     var currentDupls = finddupl.Take(iRecordCount).ToList();
     _validatonDictionary.AddError(string.Empty, string.Join(",", findduplicate) + "-Settlement POD," + string.Join(",", currentDupls) + "-Ded are duplicate PODS");
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to stick with integer maths and do `finddupl.Count() / ceilingLimit + (finddupl.Count() % ceilingLimit != 0 ? 1 : 0);`.

Comment: thank you for answer.but above we have two list of data.
"findduplicate" and "finddupl"

Comment: Displaying lists is the job of the view, not the controller.

Comment: what kind of data. can you edit your question and add more details?